# Connecting to Service Fabric using anapplication

Tags: c#, web-applications, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-service-fabric

I want to connect to Service Fabric remotely using an application. Currently, we connect using a username/password and that isn't very secure. If I run the code below, it returns that the given application isn't an administrator of the Service Fabric cluster. What I can't seem to do is add an application as an administrator, only users. Has anyone done this before? Very little online about it.

```
string token = GetAccessToken(tenantID, clusterApplicationId, clusterSecret);

                var claimsCredentials = new ClaimsCredentials();
                claimsCredentials.ServerThumbprints.Add(serverCertThumb);
                claimsCredentials.LocalClaims = token;

                try
                {
                    var fc = new FabricClient(claimsCredentials, connection);
                    var ret = fc.ClusterManager.GetClusterManifestAsync().Result;
                    Console.WriteLine(ret.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connect failed: {0}", e.Message);
                }


        private static string GetAccessToken(string tenantId, string clientId, string secretKey)
        {
            string resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
            string authorityFormat = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
            string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, authorityFormat, tenantId);
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
            var authResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential).Result;
            return authResult.AccessToken;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error that you get when you run your code?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? When I try `fc.ClusterManager.GetClusterManifestAsync().Result;`, then that call works and returns the manifest. I initialized the client with simply `new FabricClient();`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the application to get the access_token by using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), it uses its own credentials instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service. And in the azure portal, you could assign the role to applications, or just impersonate a user by delegating permissions.